# javascript function response delay

Tags: javascript, function

My code is:

```
var myvarible = "0";

wialon.util.Gis.getLocations(coordsc,function(code,responceval) {
    myvarible = responceval;
})

console.log(myvarible); // output is 0
```

How i can fix my problem? I think while it returns response code console.log runs first. please help with my problem.

Comment: Please add some context, code, and a description of the problem.

Comment: It would help if you described what your problem **is**, if you want our advice on how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that this relies on the geolocation functionality of the browser, you can't "fix" this problem. It's in the nature of asynchronous coding.

In your function `wialon.util.Gis.getLocations()` you pass in a callback. So after the (asynchronous) execution of this call, your callback will be executed.

Meanwhile the rest of your code is executed, which leads to the `console.log(myvarible);` resulting in a 0.

Change your coding style accordingly and put all code dependent on `myvarible` in the callback itself or in a function, that is called inside the callback. That way this code is only executed *after* `myvarible` is set.

So either:

```
var myvarible = "0";

wialon.util.Gis.getLocations(coordsc,function(code,responceval){
  myvarible = responceval;

  // here comes code using myvarible
  console.log(myvarible);
});
```

or

```
var myvarible = "0";

function doStuff(){
  // here comes code using myvarible
  console.log(myvarible);
};

wialon.util.Gis.getLocations(coordsc,function(code,responceval){
  myvarible = responceval;

  doStuff();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, `console.log(myvarible);` runs before `geLocations()` returns, that's why you are getting `myvariable`'s old value.

try this:

```
var myvarible = "0";

wialon.util.Gis.getLocations(coordsc,function(code,responceval){
      myvarible = responceval;
      console.log(myvarible);
})
```

This means you have to put all your `myvariable`'s related code *inside* the `getLocations()` callback function.

Answer (score 0):

As Sirko explained, you'll have to put your logging into the callback function like so:

```
var myvarible = "0";
wialon.util.Gis.getLocations(coordsc,function(code,responceval){
    myvarible = responceval;
    console.log(myvarible); // output will be responceval 
});
```